# Throwing function-like variadic macro wrapping, replacing thrown exception

Tags: c++, c++11, macros, wrapper

Suppose I have a third party library that provides a function-like `ThirdPartyMacro` macro that is:

1. Variadic and accepts arbitrary tokens, not just well formed c++ expressions. After parsing the arguments ThirdPartyMacro extracts some tokens that it assumes to be identifiers denoting variables in the scope of it's invocation, and uses them as such.
2. Evaluates to some value of a known type.
3. May throw an exception of type `ThirdPartyException`

I want to wrap this up by writing a macro `MyMacro` that will behave exactly like `ThirdPartyMacro` but throw `MyException` whenever `ThirdPartyMacro` would throw `ThirdPartyException`.

Is it possible? If so, how?

Not that due to (1) `MyMacro` cannot be a function, as it's arguments are not something that can be passed as function parameters.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A lambda will help:

```
#define MyMacro(...) \
   [&]{ try { return ThirdPartyMacro(__VA_ARGS__); } \
        catch( const ThirdPartyException& e ) \
        { throw MyException( e.what() ); } }()
```

Comment: This is valid within constraints I (under)specified. Let me restrict them. After parsing the arguments `ThirdPartyMacro` extracts some tokens that it assumes to be identifiers denoting variables in the scope of it's invocation, and uses them as such. This would require capturing them in lambda, which this doesn't do.

Comment: @yurikilochek So, capture them? Or are there any more restrictions why `[&]` (or `[=]`) won't work? In some cases you might need to mark the lambda `mutable` as well, try what works for you.

Comment: The list of said variables obviously depends on the arguments to the macro, so i cannot hardcode them. Yet i cannot pass them to the macro explicitely as this would introduce the problem of separating them from actual macro input, and would change the semantics anyway.

Comment: Disregrad that, I forgot about 'capture all'.